# Poblar Spinner Android con Ksoap

Tags: android, spinner

Amigos, primero muchas gracias por su ayuda
Quisiera consultarles como puedo poblar un spinner en android con datos de un webservice y la libreria ksoap, al momento de ejecutarlo me genera el error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

[Ws]

```html
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="LABORES">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="NOMBRE_LABOR" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<LABORES diffgr:id="LABORES1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<NOMBRE_LABOR>CORTE POMPON</NOMBRE_LABOR>
</LABORES>
<LABORES diffgr:id="LABORES2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<NOMBRE_LABOR>CORTE ANASTASIA</NOMBRE_LABOR>
</LABORES>
<LABORES diffgr:id="LABORES3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<NOMBRE_LABOR>CALIDAD POMPON</NOMBRE_LABOR>
</LABORES>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

//Clase

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner lista;
private String[] denemeList;
Button iniciar;
ArrayList<String> regions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    iniciar = findViewById(R.id.BtnStart);
    lista = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, regions);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    iniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SektorDoldur();

        }
    });
}
```

//Metodo

```
 private void SektorDoldur() {

    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ListarRegistros";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "ListarRegistros";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String URL = "http://192.168.1.11:8001/WebServiceAndroid.asmx";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);


    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    //regions = new ArrayList<String>();
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    try {

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        int count = ((SoapObject) result.getProperty(0)).getPropertyCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String str = ((SoapObject) result.getProperty(0)).getProperty(i).toString();
            regions.add(str);
        }
        Log.d("Datos", regions.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

//Log
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cargarspinner/com.example.cargarspinner.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:380)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setAdapter(AbsSpinner.java:125)
        at android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(Spinner.java:530)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.setAdapter(AppCompatSpinner.java:394)
        at com.example.cargarspinner.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Chicos, logre hacerlo de la siguiente manera

Este es el metodo del Web Service

```
    <WebMethod()>
Public Function Labores() As List(Of String)
    conexion.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NOMBRE_LABOR FROM LABORES"
    cmd.Connection = conexion

    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim gList As New List(Of String)

    If rdr.HasRows Then
        While rdr.Read
            gList.Add(rdr.Item("NOMBRE_LABOR").ToString())
        End While
    End If


    Return gList
End Function
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


String list[];
boolean exc = false;
Button iniciar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    iniciar = findViewById(R.id.BtnStart);
    new addassdist().execute();
}

class addassdist extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Labores";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "Labores";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String URL = "http://192.168.1.11:8001/WebServiceAndroid.asmx";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading data");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            System.out.println("response" + response);
            int intPropertyCount = response.getPropertyCount();
            list = new String[intPropertyCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < intPropertyCount; i++) {
                list[i] = response.getProperty(i).toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exc = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (exc) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            spinner();
            exc = false;
        }
    }
}

public void spinner() {

    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}
```

}